# Finding an analytical expression for the eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to know if there is any way to find an analytical expression for the eigen values of the following matrix.

$$
A^h = \frac{1}{h^4}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  5&-4&1&&&&&&\\
  -4&6&-4&1&&&&\bigcirc&\\
  1&-4&6&-4&1&&&&\\
  &\ddots  & \ddots  & \ddots & \ddots&&&  \\
  &&\ddots  & \ddots  & \ddots & \ddots&&  \\
  &&&&1&-4&6&-4&1\\
  &\bigcirc&&&&1&-4&6&-4\\
  &&&&&&1&-4&5\\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

I have heard that it is possible through DFT, but I am not sure how to proceed with that. The size of the matrix is $N \times N$ and $h = \frac{1}{N}$.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this come from cubic splines?

Comment: Well, it actually came from the discretization of the bi-harmonic equation with a 5 point finite difference stencil.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $h=1$ for simplicity (rescaling is trivial).
Note that $A^h=B^2$, where $B$ is the symmetric tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix with non-zero elements $(-1,2,-1)$, i.e.
$$
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \dots \\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0 &\dots \\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & \dots \\
& & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The eigenvalues of symmetric tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices are well known and can be found in many texts. For $B$, the eigenvalues are
$$
\lambda_k(B) = 2 \left( 1-\cos{\left( \frac{k \pi}{N+1} \right)} \right).
$$
It immediately follows that the eigenvalues of $A^h$ are given by
$$
\lambda_k(A) = \lambda_k^2(B) = 4 \left( 1-\cos{\left( \frac{k \pi}{N+1} \right)} \right)^2.
$$

Comment: So simple when you see the trick! Very nice. And the eigenvalues of the tridiagonal matrix are indeed easy (there is a three term recurrence for the determinant).

Comment: Great observation. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if possible could you please give me some books or sources which tell about how to derive the eigen values of toeplitz matrix ?